# How to render .jsp from database without .jsp physical file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

I am developing an application where I will have only loader.jsp which will load all other jsp files from the database. Like I am having all the coding for jsp file in database so that i can able to change the html content without restart the server in database itself.

Is there any framework already existing to implement this and what is the best way to achieve this?

If yes for render .jsp file dynamically, how to render css and js dependency also dynamically?

So my exact requirement is, I will have only loader.jsp which will load all other pages stored in database based on the path param.

```
http://localhost:8081/myApplication?page=mypage
```

TECHNOLOGIES USING: java spring boot

NOTE 1: I am not gonna render based of conditions or some parts of the file, I need to render entire page as it is from the database columns.

NOTE 2: if loading .jsp is not possible since jsp code need to be compiled, then can i load .html file? ex: loader.jsp will load a.html, b.html, c.html from  database

NOTE 3: Am building application where user can able to drag and drop UI elements to create webpages and once if they save, their changes need to reflect on run time without restart. like they have one page in their own application itself to change their UI elements.

Comment: Since the server has to compile the JSP page into a Java class, this is not easy to achieve. It would also be very inefficient because the compilation has to happen for every request, since you don't know if the JSP in the DB has changed.

Comment: so it that possible to do for .html file? @Henry which is loader.jsp file will load html contents (in db: a.html, b.html, c.html...)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But the pages would be static unless you invent some templating mechanism. Why not store the html pages in a simple web server then?

Comment: my main objective is I should not restart the server to reflect the changed. The changed which I made should be reflect in run time. @Henry

Comment: Be very, very cautious with such an objective. It has many, many disadvantages: 1: it's impossible to unit test the actual code being used. 2: you can't version control the code anymore, revert to an older version in case of a bug, comment on why some changes were made. 3: it's of course slower. 4: it's way harder to edit the code, since it isn't stored in files but in the database. 5. it allows, or even forces you to deploy new code without ever testing it.

Comment: You *will* have to stop the server at some point for other cases, so you'd better find another strategy that allows redeploying without being down (like two servers not redeployed at the same time), if that's important to you.

Comment: forget about testing and version control, I need the constrain only about performance. If I replace database with some cache server or something else, it that will be comparatively much performance right? @JBNizet

Comment: so is there any other way to get that done. I guess we can get this by using thymeleaf. Is that true? @JBNizet

Comment: Being slower doesn't mean it will be *too slow*. Do the simplest thing you can imagine, and optimize only if needed. But, again, this looks like a terrible idea to me. And you will have to stop the server anyway every time you need to change code, and not just html snippets.

Comment: am working on POC only. So decently will think any other any to do.  Performance is impact, yes i agree. But, I am building dynamic solution. I need to have my html as dynamic contents without restart the server. Is there any other way to do? @JBNizet

Comment: still not clear what you really need. Is a CMS a solution for you?

Comment: yes. Exactly like CMS. @Henry

Comment: Am building application where user can able to drag and drop UI elements to create webpages and once if they save, their changes need to reflect on run time without restart. like they have one page in their application itself to change their UI elements. @JBNizet

Comment: @Henry please refer above